# Render css class in variable in condition

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to create component where I will set 2 properties:

1. string property for class name which should be set
2. boolean property which resolve if this class will be added

my component looks like this:

```
<template>
      <span v-bind:class="{ classProp : booleanProp}"></span>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
      props: {
        classProp: {
          type: String,
          default: 'bg-alert'
        },
        booleanProp: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
      }
    }
</script>
```

When I use this component as you can see in following code span element has class **classProp** instead of **bg-success**

```
<my-component :booleanProp="true" :classProp="bg-success"></my-component>
```

required output:

```
<span class="bg-success"></span>
```

given output:

```
<span class="classProp"></span>
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

Vue's [object syntax for class](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) will use `classProp` as the class name (same as would do it JavaScript for an object key), instead of computing it. For that you have to ES6's [computed property name](http://es6-features.org/#ComputedPropertyNames) syntax:

```html
<template>
      <span v-bind:class="{ [classProp] : booleanProp}"></span>
</template>
```

Also, when using `v-bind` (or the shorthand, `:`) dont forget to pass strings as you would in JavaScript, enclosed in quotes (or, you could omit the binding and instead pass it as a regular prop `classProp="bg-success"`):

```html
<my-component :booleanProp="true" :classProp="'bg-success'"></my-component>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yuriy636/jxbopcnk/) (don't mind the kebab-case props)